# Finding singularities and residuals

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(2z-1)}$. Then $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{2}{2z-1}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k-\frac{1}{z(1-\frac{1}{2z})}$$
$$=-(1+z+z^2+z^3+ \dots +z^k+ \dots)- \frac{1}{z}*(1+\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{1}{(2z)^2}+\dots +\frac{1}{(2z)^k}+\dots)$$

Therefore, the origin is an essential singularity of $f(z)$ with residue $-1$.

This is the work I have came up with which makes sense computationally wise to me but there is obviously an error.

Comment: You need to expand around the singularity itself to conclude from an infinite number of negative powered terms that it is an essential singularity. You've expanded around zero, not around either of the singularities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two singularities $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, so you need to expand around these singularities.

Around $1$ :

$$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{2}{2z-1}\\&=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{2}{2(z-1)-1}\\&= \frac{1}{z-1}-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n2^n(z-1)^n\\&= \frac{1}{z-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n2^{n+1}(z-1)^n \end{align}$$

So $1$ is a pole of order $1$ with residue $=1$.

Around $\frac{1}{2}$ :
$$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{2}{2z-1}\\&= \frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}} \\&= \frac{-2}{1-2(z-\frac{1}{2})}-\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}\\&= -2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n(z-\frac{1}{2})^n-\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}} \\&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-2^{n+1}(z-\frac{1}{2})^n-\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}  \end{align}$$

So $\frac{1}{2}$ is a pole of order $1$ with residue $=-1$.